# spring boot and spring security 4.0

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I have REST and websocket application developed with Spring Boot (1.2.2).  I would like to take advantage of the websocket security features added in Spring Security 4.0, but Spring Boot pulls in Spring Security 3.2.6.

Even if I update to the latest GA Spring Boot (1.2.6), I still won't get Spring Security 4.0.

What's the path forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, overriding the version of a dependency to pick up a new major version isn't recommended. The safest approach is to use Spring Boot 1.3.0.M5 or wait for 1.3.0.RELEASE which, at the time of writing is scheduled for mid-October.

That said, the [changes required to upgrade to Spring Security 4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/ba3d4e9e3c1a045916446cdd8820ec45886f23b5) were pretty minimal. Depending on what other projects you're using, overriding the Spring Security dependency version in your pom may well work. If you're using Thymeleaf, Spring Social or Spring Web Services then you'll have more work to do.

Comment: Good to know that Boot 1.3.0 will include Security 4.0.  That's the way forward, then.  Thanks.